# Automatically fill the search box on question pages

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags, search

The search field is auto-filled with the tag name on search pages. I think the same should be done for question pages, or at least those with a lot of answers. This would make it easier to check for duplicate answers to such questions before posting.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Cleaning up search questions here...declining this for the reasons @Jeff lists below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That would only benefit .001% of questions -- most have far less than 30+ answers -- and it would be annoying the other 99.999% of the time.

Even if we did it *only* on questions with 30+ answers, why would I want to *encourage* so-called "questions" with that many answers?